# vba for each element loop error occurs at second loop

Tags: vba, loops, internet-explorer, foreach, nested

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to scrape data from a website. I've used nested loop. When the innermost loop finishes for the first time, the next loop starts for marakez.

Actual problem is that when 'for each in schl2' loop repeats for second time, IE crashes and loop is unable to proceed. I have mentioned in code.

Here is my code

```
    Sub ResultDownloader()
    
    ' here I define elemnts for the loop
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LocData")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim imagePath As Object
                    
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    startrec = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    startrec = startrec + 1

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    '        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    ' here I define Object to sendkeys
    Dim SHELL_OBJECT
    SHELL_OBJECT = "WScript.Shell"
    Set objShell = CreateObject(SHELL_OBJECT)
    

    
        Record2Strt = (sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row) + 1
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "some_url"

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
                    

Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim selectElement, selectElement2, selectElement3 As HTMLSelectElement
Dim evtChange As Object
Set Doc = IE.Document
Dim dist1, tehsl1, mrkz1, schl1 As Object
Dim dist2, tehsl2, mrkz2, schl2 As Variant
Dim distlen, thsllen, mrkzlen, schllen As Byte
Dim dst, tsl, mrkz, schl As Byte
Dim elt3, elt4, elt5, elt6 As Variant


Set evtChange = Doc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
evtChange.initEvent "change", True, False


      Set dist1 = Doc.querySelector("Select[name=districts]")
      Set dist2 = dist1.querySelectorAll("option")
      distlen = dist1.querySelectorAll("option").Length
      dst = 0
      For Each elt3 In dist2
       distnme = elt3.innerText
       If distnme <> "All Districts" Then
       dist1.getElementsByTagName("option")(dst).Selected = True
       Set selectElement2 = Doc.getElementsByTagName("option")(dst)
       selectElement2.dispatchEvent evtChange
       Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 0.5, Now)
       
       
       Set tehsl1 = Doc.querySelector("Select[name=tehsil]")
       Set tehsl2 = tehsl1.querySelectorAll("option")
       thsllen = tehsl1.querySelectorAll("option").Length
       tsl = 0
       For Each elt4 In tehsl2
       thslnme = elt4.innerText
       If thslnme <> "All Tehsils" Then
       Set tehsl1 = Doc.querySelector("Select[name=tehsil]")
       tehsl1.getElementsByTagName("option")(tsl).Selected = True
       Set selectElement3 = tehsl1.getElementsByTagName("option")(tsl)
       selectElement3.dispatchEvent evtChange
       Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 0.5, Now)
       

       Set mrkz1 = Doc.querySelector("Select[name=markaz]")
       Set mrkz2 = mrkz1.querySelectorAll("option")
       mrkzlen = mrkz1.querySelectorAll("option").Length
       mrkz = 0
       For Each elt5 In mrkz2
       mrkznm = elt5.innerText
       If mrkznm <> "All Marakez" Then
       Set mrkz1 = Doc.querySelector("Select[name=markaz]")
       mrkz1.getElementsByTagName("option")(mrkz).Selected = True
       Set selectElement4 = mrkz1.getElementsByTagName("option")(mrkz)
       selectElement4.dispatchEvent evtChange
       Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 0.5, Now)
       
           Set schl1 = Doc.querySelector("Select[name=school]")
           Set schl2 = schl1.querySelectorAll("option")
           schllen = schl1.querySelectorAll("option").Length
           schl = 0
    '               second loop problem
    '               when for each elt6 in schl2 starts IE crashes

           On Error Resume Next
           For Each elt6 In schl2
           Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 0.5, Now)
           schlnm = elt6.innerText
           If schlnm <> "All Schools" Then
           Set schl1 = Doc.querySelector("Select[name=school]")
           schl1.getElementsByTagName("option")(schl).Selected = True
           Set selectElement5 = schl1.getElementsByTagName("option")(schl)
           selectElement5.dispatchEvent evtChange

               sht.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Value = LastRow
               sht.Range("B" & LastRow + 1).Value = distnme
               sht.Range("C" & LastRow + 1).Value = thslnme
               sht.Range("D" & LastRow + 1).Value = mrkznm
               sht.Range("E" & LastRow + 1).Value = schlnm
               LastRow = LastRow + 1
           End If       'for school

           
           schl = schl + 1
           If schllen = schl Then
           GoTo new_marakez
           On Error Resume Next
           End If
           Next         'ele6

       End If       'for marakez
new_marakez:
       mrkz = mrkz + 1
       If mrkzlen = mrkz Then
       Exit For
       GoTo new_tehsil
       End If
       
       Next         'ele5
       On Error Resume Next
       End If       'for tehsils
new_tehsil:
       tsl = tsl + 1
       If thsllen = tsl Then
       GoTo new_dist
       End If
       
       Next         'ele4
       On Error Resume Next
       End If       'for districts
new_dist:
        dst = dst + 1
       If distlen = dst Then
       GoTo stopp
       End If
       
       Next         'ele 3
       On Error Resume Next
       
  

stopp:
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please inform me which IE version you are using? do you mean the IE browser crashed on the `For Each elt6 In schl2` line? Does IE browser or VBA editor show any error while IE gets crashed? If yes, please inform us about it. If possible try to post the sample HTML code so that I can try to test the VBA code with it. Please inform us, what are the manual steps to perform this operation? It can help us to check whether there is any logical issue with the VBA code. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: IE version is displayed as Version 2004(OS Build 19041.685),

Comment: Yes IE browser crashes and restarts at 'For Each elt6 In schl2' line and the error shown is 'Internet Explorer has stopped working. When I closes the IE it restarts and VBA code proceeds to next line but it doesn't work.

Comment: I suggest you comment the `On Error Resume Next` line before the For-each loop and also comment the `On Error Resume Next` line within the loop. Check after commenting the lines what error it produces and provide information about it. Please try to provide the HTML code, so that we can make a test and try to debug the code.

Comment: Tested by commenting On Error Resume Next but result is same. IE crashes

Comment: I've tested the code vigorously and found when inner For Each Element loop finishes for the first time and outer For Each Element Loop changes the value to next. then this problem occurs. And then inner loop fails to start.

Comment: Now after careful debugging, I've found that in (For Each elt6 in schl2), the "elt6' is not accepting the new values for second loop. If I start a new loop where elt6 is not used but a new variable is used, the loop goes on smoothly. I think, either existing is not emptying properly. although I have used set elt6=nothing also but in vain. Any Idea?

Comment: Please try to provide the necessary HTML code to reproduce the issue. You can replace the confidential data with dummy values, we do not require any private information. Without checking and testing the code on my side I am not able to provide any solid suggestions about the cause and possible solution for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

There is apparently a bug when using querySelectorAll with a generic object for your elements, in your case here 'schl2.', and using a for each...next loop. I solved this by using a standard for...next loop basically limiting the for loop, in your case, schl2.Length - 1. However, this will not work unless you define schl2 as MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection. If you leave this as generic, the schl2.Length will be NULL. The code below shows how I got around the problem.

```
`'Create html object to hold IE Document
Set html = IE.Document

Debug.Print "********* GET FIELDS ******" & vbCrLf

Dim res1 As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
Set res1 = html.querySelectorAll("#HtmlOutputReportResults2_Explorer_Filters_Column option:checked")

For r = 0 To res1.Length - 1
    If res1(r).innerText <> "..." Then
        Debug.Print "res1.Text: " & res1(r).innerText
    End If
Next

Debug.Print vbCrLf & "********* GET OPERATORS ******" & vbCrLf

Dim res2 As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
Set res2 = html.querySelectorAll("#HtmlOutputReportResults2_Explorer_Filters_Operator option:checked")

For r = 0 To res2.Length - 1
    If res2(r).innerText <> "..." Then
        Debug.Print "res2.Text: " & res2(r).innerText
    End If
Next`
```